# Странный вывод в txt файл. (вывод RGB данных пикселей картинок в txt файл)

Tags: java, файлы, изображения, текст

Попробовал найти и вывести RGB данные одной картинки (ну конечно программа должна работать для любых картинок) в один соответствующий txt файл.

Начнем с кода программы.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ReadAndWriteImage
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("I:\\1\\Esdeath - war music collection1.jpg");
        File file2 = new File("I:\\1\\Esdeath - war music collection1.txt");
        // Getting pixel color by position x and y
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file2);

        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                int clr = image.getRGB(x, y);
                int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16; //ну это не моя импровизация, а скопированное решение из одного ответа со стаковерфлоу
                int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8; //то же самое и про green и blue
                int blue = clr & 0x000000ff;             
                printWriter.print(red + ", " + green + ", " + blue + "; ");
            }
        }
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```

И так, с кодом теперь ознакомлены.

Теперь насчет проблемы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что посоветуете сделать? Как можно исправить эту даже не знаю как называть, ладно назовем это неисправностью.

Теперь дополнительная информация: Я решил попробовать вывести эти данные не одним файлом а множеством мелких txt файлов, количество которых зависит от высоты картинки (скажем 1280х720) - выводит 720 штук txt файлов.  Но к сожалению, самый последний файл имеет ту же неисправность (что и описана на втором пункте на скрине txt файла)

Есть еще кое что, что вызывает волнение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это в случае если картинка недостаточно хорошо видна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это еще не весь цирк.

я это сделал скрин txt, которую создала и заполнила сама программа, а вот ниже я сделал скрин того, что вывело IDE при попытке читать 800-ый (в смысле последний кусок данных) txt файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удивительным образом, выводит правильную последовательность, по крайней мере на вид правильный, так как правило "цифра,цифра,цифра;" соблюдена.

Но почему тогда если напрямую открыть txt файл через блокнот - выводится неправильный вид?

вот дополнительный скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как то запутался я.

Comment: Я бы в первую очередь попробовал бы не использовать стандартный виндовый блокнот - он очень плох. Попробуйте открывать ваши файлы через что-то получше, например `Notepad++`

Comment: В смысле, может быть проблема в том, что txt правильно выводится, но блокнот неправильно показывает данные?

Comment: Попробовал Notepad++.  Доволен результатом и слегка озадачен. Получается Notepad, ну обычный блокнот - имеет баги, или это не совсем так?

Comment: Пожалуй проблема была исключительно в обычном блокноте. В Notpad++ все хорошо работает.

Comment: Я не знаю точно в чём там дело, но стандартные блокноты не могут отобразить реальное содержимое файла или по умолчанию имеют настройки, согласно которым пытаются интерпретировать содержимое файла согласно какому-то стандарту. Т.е. заточены под юзера, не под программиста. Например, такие же проблемы будут и при попытке открыть `*.html` файл в стандартном блокноте на `macOS`. Ещё, вроде, винда пытается открывать `*.xml` файлы через `excel` с плачевным результатом. А некоторые юзеры открывают `*.xml` в `Word` - там вообще всё очень плохо - лишнее форматирование появляется.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Приму к сведению на будущее. Спасибо за быструю поддержку.   Notepad++ очень понравился (пока не знаю про минусы, возможно они есть, но пока я ни одного из них не увидел), надеюсь даже если и есть минусы, то они не такие хардкорные как случай с блокнотом.

Comment: "почему все строки имеют разные длины" - очевидно потому значения компонентов цветов могут быть от 0 до 255 (от 1 до 3 символов), а значения в строках разные. Удобнее выводить в шестнадцатеричном виде от 00 до FF, тогда все ровно будет.